# Не учитывается последний элемент в цикле

Tags: javascript

Есть такой вот код:

```js
function getMaxProfit(arr) {
  var minIdx = 0;
  var maxIdx = 1;
  var currMin = 0;
  var maxProfit = 0;

  if (arr.length < 2) {
    throw new Error("Needs more data");
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log('i' + i);
    // new min.
    if (arr[i] < arr[currMin]) {
      console.log('i opa' + i);
      currMin = i;
    }
    console.log(arr[maxIdx], arr[minIdx])
    console.log(arr[i], arr[currMin])
    // new best profit
    if (arr[maxIdx] - arr[minIdx] < arr[i] - arr[currMin]) {
      console.log('i vita' + i);
      maxIdx = i;
      minIdx = currMin;
    }

  }
  console.log(maxIdx);


  console.log(minIdx);
  maxProfit = arr[maxIdx] - arr[minIdx];
  return maxProfit;
}

var arr1 = [80, 80, 80, 80, 70];
var arr2 = [1]; //for test
console.log('max profit = ' + getMaxProfit(arr1));
```

Данная функция - функция нахождения максимальной выгоды.

Например, при входных данных `100,100,100,90,100`

Выгода будет макс - мин, то есть  `100 - 90 = 10.`

Проблема в том, что алгоритм не берет в учет последний элемент, если элемент имеет минимальное значение, и первый элемент, если он имеет максимальное значение. И сам я не вижу причины. Прошу подсказать в чем моя ошибка.

Comment: Почему бы не использовать стандартные `Math.max.apply(null, [10, 20, 40]) `или `Math.min.apply(null, [10, 20, 40])` ?

Comment: Что получается на выходе и что должно быть?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так оно работает и должно выглядеть. Первый блок `if` правильный, а второй не правильный. Он должен быть просто обратным со знаком `>`. А `currMin` вообще не нужно.

```js
function getMaxProfit(arr) {
  var minIdx = 0;
  var maxIdx = 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < arr[minIdx]) {
      minIdx = i;
    }
    if (arr[i] > arr[maxIdx]) {
      maxIdx = i;
    }
  }

  console.log(minIdx,maxIdx);
  var maxProfit = arr[maxIdx] - arr[minIdx];
  return maxProfit;
}

var arr1 = [80, 80, 80, 80, 70];
console.log('max profit = ' + getMaxProfit(arr1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужный результат можно получить всего лишь одной строкой кода:

```js
var maxProfit = Math.max(...arr1) - Math.min(...arr1)
```